# He earned a law degree from or at Harvard Law School?

Tags: prepositions

What is correct? He earned a law degree at Harvard Law School or from Harvard Law School?

Comment: With "received", *from* wins handily.  But with "earned", *from* and *at* are neck-and-neck. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=earned+his+law+degree+from%2Cearned+his+law+degree+at%2Creceived+his+law+degree+from%2Creceived+his+law+degree+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearned%20his%20law%20degree%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cearned%20his%20law%20degree%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creceived%20his%20law%20degree%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creceived%20his%20law%20degree%20at%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. "He earned a law degree at Harvard Law School" says that he earned a law degree while he was at Harvard while "... from Harvard Law School" says that he earned a law degree and that law degree was given to him by Harvard (it was from Harvard).

Comment: Yes, at least hypothetically, he could have been enrolled in ( = at) Harvard Law, but gotten the degree from Diplomamill U :-)

Comment: @jamesqf indeed, but he would have to describe it too much when saying the truth of the situation: "I earned a law degree at Harvard Law School, from Diplomamill U," which is confusing and therefore he'd probably just stick with "I earned a law degree at Harvard" or "I earned a law degree from Diplomamaill U."